# how come PDO::bindParam is so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**SOLVED:** The quoting of values in second test seemed to be the problem.
Instead doing 'VALUES ($id, $t1....)' I needed to do 'VALUES ("$id", "$t1".....), in the second test this was indeed throwing errors. which I couldn't see, only after printing them manually.

Hey there I've been working with bindParam lately and noticed the load time of my page went up dramatically.

So I spend a few hours to diagnose the problem and it seems that bindParam is using **A LOT** more processing time then the old fashion way (using parameters in query directly)

To make sure the results are valid, I did both tests twice.

Here is my test:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
    unset($t);
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306', 'root', 'root');
    $dbh->query('USE Web_Amicrom_HQ');
    $t['start'] = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $t1 = string_random(240);
        $t2 = string_random(240);
        $t3 = string_random(1000);
        $ins = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES(:1, :2, now(), :3, :4)');
        $ins->bindParam(':1', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $ins->bindParam(':2', $t1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $ins->bindParam(':3', $t2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $ins->bindParam(':4', $t3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $ins->execute();
    }
    $t['loop_fact'] = microtime(true);

    echo "---- with bindParam ----\n";
    $str_result_bench = mini_bench_to($t);
    echo $str_result_bench; // string return
    echo "\n\n";
}

for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
    unset($t);
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306', 'root', 'root');
    $dbh->query('USE Web_Amicrom_HQ');
    $t['start'] = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $t1 = string_random(240);
        $t2 = string_random(240);
        $t3 = string_random(1000);
        $ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES($id, $t1, now(), $t2, $t3)");
        $ins->execute();
    }
    $t['loop_fact'] = microtime(true);

    echo "---- with parameter in query ----\n";
    $str_result_bench = mini_bench_to($t);
    echo $str_result_bench; // string return
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

**Results:**

```
---- with bindParam ----
total time : 3136.148ms


---- with bindParam ----
total time : 2645.822ms


---- with parameter in query ----
total time : 41.693ms


---- with parameter in query ----
total time : 52.9752ms
```

Things I tried.

Change quotes from Double to Single - No difference

bindParam without parameter type (e.g PDO::PARAM_INT) - No difference

Changed all param names (e.g :1 to :id etc.) - No difference

This is a big performance difference, especially for just a few queries.

Comment: Have you compared it to using `execute()` with an array?

Comment: Maybe you could include all the unknown function so we can see if we get the same results

Comment: The SQL in the second for loop wont work!

Comment: When I fix the bugs, each loop runs in less than a second

Comment: This is a typical example of a quickly written benchmark that does not actually test what it was designed to do.

Comment: You are including the time it takes to generate randon number and random strings

Comment: You are preparing a query inside the loop. That can be done outside the loop as it only needs to be done once

Comment: @roland starke , yes data is inserted i just simply removed the real IP address for privacy reasons.

Comment: @RyanVincent it cannot be a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **Why is PDO::bindParam so slow?**

A: **PDO::bindParam isn't slow.**

The benchmark test demonstrated in the question isn't a valid measure of bindParam performance.

The second test is going to throw errors for nearly every INSERT. That's because the string literals (?) are not enclosed in single quotes. I originally thought those would be interpreted as numeric. (Confusingly, we don't see a specification for the return from `string_random(240)`.  We don't see a definition of that function, or even any examples of what that returns.)

If that's returning a string of 240 characters which doesn't represent a valid numeric literal... the benchmark is comparing inserts of rows  ~1500 characters (using bindParam) vs. no rows inserted.

My original answer (below) indicates modifications to the two tests so that they perform equivalent functions. This would be more valid comparison of bindParam vs not bindParam.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

For improved performance, call `prepare` and `bindParam` functions one time, before entering the loop. (It's not necessary to call prepare on the same SQL statement multiple times.)

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES(:1, :2, NOW(), :3, :4)'; 
    $ins = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $id = 0;
    $t1 = 0;
    $t2 = 0;
    $t3 = 0;
    $ins->bindParam(':1', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ins->bindParam(':2', $t1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->bindParam(':3', $t2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->bindParam(':4', $t3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $t1 = string_random(240);
        $t2 = string_random(240);
        $t3 = string_random(1000);
        $ins->execute();
    }
```

If we were using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, we would need to do the `bindValue` immediately before the execute, each time.

---

For the second test (not using bindParam), the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, unlike the first test.  To make this second test equivalent to the first, we'd need to ensure that the values are properly escaped so they are safe for inclusion in the SQL text.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $t1 = string_random(240);
        $t2 = string_random(240);
        $t3 = string_random(1000);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES ( " 
             . $dbh->quote( $id ) . ", "
             . $dbh->quote( $t1 ) . ", "
             . "NOW(), "
             . $dbh->quote( $t2 ) . ", "
             . $dbh->quote( $t3 ) . ")";
        $ins = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $ins->execute();
    }
```

Note that the quote function does more than just put quotes around values. It also "escapes" single quotes included within the text, and other characters that would be interpreted by MySQL. (In the original second test, we don't see single quotes around the values, so it looks like MySQL would have evaluated those in a numeric context. We'd expect a lot of those rows would have "0" in the t1, t2 and t3 columns.

I'd be interested in seeing the comparison in timing of these two (modified) tests.

Comment: 1. It won't help with his setup at all. 2. It cannot explain such a HUGE difference.

Comment: Which makes your answer a mere off-topic.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: 1) the modifications I suggested *do* help with setting up a measurement of the performance impact of bindParam, by eliminating other differences. 2) it does explain "such a HUGE difference" if one of the loops is inserting rows, and the other test is throwing syntax errors.  You may believe that OP comparison is a valid measure of the performance of "bindParam". You are entitled to your opinion. You are free to downvote my answer. There's only one downvote so far, so feel free to add yours.

Comment: The only thing that your answer explains is why a non-bindParam version could be slow. While the OP's experience is quite opposite.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Quite to the contrary. The bindParam version could be inserting rows of 1500 characters. The non-bindParam version is issuing insert statements that fail very early in statement processing, during the syntax check. The non-bindParam is doing a lot less work. It's not performing a semantics check, developing an execution plan, obtaining locks, checking constraints, accessing blocks performing block split operations, generating rollback, writing changes to the binary log/innodb log, releasing locks. We expect that the OP non-bindParam version would be *faster*.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Although any speculations on the poorly written test are of little value, the first sentence of your post is good enough for the answer.

Comment: The quoting of values in second test seemed to be the problem.
Instead doing 'VALUES ($id, $t1....)' I needed to do 'VALUES ("$id", "$t1".....), in the second test this was indeed throwing errors. which I couldn't see, only after printing them manually.

Answer (score 2):

In line 3 in your code you have the following error `host=127` that is why `bindParam` has too slow benchmarks

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306', 'root', 'root');
```

**EDIT**
In your example you can avoid connecting to MySQL server 4 times (2 loops of 2 times each) and not close the connection once. Also there is not need to have an extra query to `USE` database Web_Amicrom_HQ, you can pass that piece of information in the connection.

Full code

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Web_Amicrom_HQ', 'root', 'root');
    for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {   
            $start = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
            $t1 = string_random(240);
            $t2 = string_random(240);
            $t3 = string_random(1000);
            $ins = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES(:1, :2, now(), :3, :4)');
            $ins->bindParam(':1', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ins->bindParam(':2', $t1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ins->bindParam(':3', $t2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ins->bindParam(':4', $t3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ins->execute();
        }
        echo "---- with bindParam ----\n";
        echo microtime(true) - $start; // time elapsed
        echo "\n\n";
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {

        $start = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
            $t1 = string_random(240);
            $t2 = string_random(240);
            $t3 = string_random(1000);
            $ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (id, t1, dt, t2, t3) VALUES($id, $t1, now(), $t2, $t3)");
            $ins->execute();
        }
        echo "---- with bindParam ----\n";
        echo microtime(true) - $start; // time elapsed
        echo "\n\n";
    }
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: In your database connection in your example you have two different host values. 127 and 127.0.0.1, for the first one you get 3300 seconds response... for the second 40 seconds, you still don't think that there is a connection problem in the first one?

Comment: Is in your running code host=127 in the example of `bindParam`? If yes can you make it `127.0.0.1` and write me the benchmark results?

Comment: Oh, I see. It wasn't clear whether the code you displayed was the erroneous version or the fixed version. I took it as the former, and saw nothing wrong with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I think if you correct this probable mistype and run the script again you will see that `bindParam` is faster.

Comment: @AndrewCheong i did not understood that, sorry, it is a bit late at night here :)

Comment: No worries, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: As I said before in another comment, there is no error in my PDO connection setup, I put 127.0.0.1 in there for privacy reasons, As I don't want to put IP addresses of my servers on stackoverflow (public)

Comment: In most web servers MySQL connection host is probably either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Can you please try the above altered code and share the results? @PiotrGajdowski